# Dynamically pass value in jQuery.ajax() data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am making an AJAX call to subscribe a user and want to pass a value dynamically in data attribute. How do I do that?

```
function submitFormWithAction(value, isSubscribedPortal) {
    //value and isSubscribedPortal is passed using jsp
    checkSelection();
    brand = ${userDataBean.profileConfiguration.profileData.profileFields['AutomobileBrand']}
    if (value == 'subscribe') {
        document.browseForm.action = "subscription.wfv";
        document.browseForm.method = "POST";
    } else if (value == 'addProfile') {
        document.browseForm.action = "addProfile.wfv?isSendAlert=false";
        document.browseForm.method = "POST";
    } else if (value == 'editProfile') {
        document.browseForm.action = "saveProfile.wfv?isSendAlert=false";
        document.browseForm.method = "POST";
    }
    if (isSubscribedPortal) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "saveViewData.wfv",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content'));
            },
            // viewData is a Map<String,String> in UserDataBean.java
            // brand will be set after form is submitted, so how can I dynamically pass brand
            data:"viewData[message]= Your Profile for" + brand + "has been saved",
            success: function (msg){
                document.browseForm.submit();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("some error");
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('Subscribing to portal');
        $.when(
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "subscription.wfv",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content'));
                },
                data: "nextView=dummy&currentVertical=portal&isSendAlert=false",
            }),
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "saveViewData.wfv",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="_csrf"]').attr('content'));
                },
                // data: "viewData[message]=Your Search Profile is saved",
            })
        ).then(function (msg) {
            document.browseForm.submit();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `data` is the data you want to send *to the server*. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: no I dont want to send data to server. I am writing a walk through to clarify:
1.User will fill a form 
2.He will click on "Submit"
3.Next page he will see a generic "homePage.jsp" with a notification-"Your profile for **Honda [ie, brand which is dynamically passed after form submission]** has been saved"
4. To achieve this generic feature. I have included notification.jsp in homePage.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're constructing the `data` string by hand, you need to call `encodeURIComponent` to make sure that special characters are encoded, such as translating space to `+` and other special characters to percent-codes.

```
data: encodeURIComponent('viewData[message]') + '=' + encodeURIComponent("Your Profile for" + brand +"has been saved"),
```

However, it's simpler to let jQuery do this for you, by specifying an object instead of a string.

```
data: { viewdata: { message: "Your Profile for" + brand +"has been saved" } },
```

Comment: Hey I am really sorry to be such a hurry[actually I passed some other variable whose value was already set before form submission,which worked ] and gave it correct. But what I wanted was something I am setting in the present form and pass it. Let me try I guess my brand is null thats why it shows nothing but for previous case it worked. Let me test.

Comment: Something like `brand = $("#fieldID").val()`.

Comment: thanks !!..alot :) ...i made a mistake previously...it worked !!